# Issue with Laravel Carbon next() day

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, php-carbon

I have this code :

```
return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $given_date, $user_timezone)->next($user_day); //  $user_day = 'Monday';
```

which gives error:

> Undefined index: Monday

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the function itself:

```php
// Carbon\CarbonInterface
/**
     * Modify to the next occurrence of a given modifier such as a day of
     * the week. If no modifier is provided, modify to the next occurrence
     * of the current day of the week. Use the supplied constants
     * to indicate the desired dayOfWeek, ex. static::MONDAY.
     *
     * @param string|int|null $modifier
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function next($modifier = null);
```

You can derive that you need to use the carbon constants, which is `Carbon::MONDAY`. Looking at the class itself, that resolves to `1`.

So you could also pass any integer from `0` (sunday) to `6` (saturday).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) you can also use `echo $dt->next('Wednesday');`

Comment: hm yes it does state it there, not sure why but the docblock clearly says "Use the supplied constants"

Comment: @kerbholz you might want to check your version because `Carbon::now()->next('Monday')` works without issues in my code.

Comment: Without issues, yes, that's what I was saying ;) You should be able to use regular day names (`Monday`...) in the `next()` method.

Comment: @Flame I upgraded the version and its now working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

share the values for $given_date and $user_timezone, that will help in debugging. Also Carbon::createFromFormat() generate a carbon object, wonder why it is throwing undefined index, do a dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $given_date, $user_timezone)); and see whats coming